# Count rows between NA's

Tags: r

i'm trying to get a specific count from a previously created result set. I need a count of rows between rows that contain NA's. An aggregation of values of these rows are not of interest, only the count.

Below a quite simplified example which hopefully better explains what i'm talking about. At left hand the actual data and at right hand the desired result.

```
+------+-------+---+------+--------+
| TIME | Value | - | TIME | Result |
+------+-------+---+------+--------+
|   10 | NA    | - |   20 |      2 |
|   20 | 0     | - |   60 |      3 |
|   30 | 1     | - |      |        |
|   40 | NA    | - |      |        |
|   50 | NA    | - |      |        |
|   60 | 30    | - |      |        |
|   70 | 68    | - |      |        |
|   80 | 0     | - |      |        |
|   90 | NA    | - |      |        |
+------+-------+---+------+--------+
```

Any comments are welcome. In case additional input is needed please leave a message.

Comment: In the future, please post your data in a way that others can easily copy-and-paste into their R console. `dupt` is usually helpful for such purposes.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto: Thanks for your hint regarding example data posting. I'm quite new to stackoverflow and will keep this in mind for later post.

Comment: Can you take a look at [the comments under this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26762869/1270695) and let us know how you would like to treat cases where the "value" column *does not* start with an `NA` value as the first value?

Comment: @ Ananda Matho: Actually the "Result" column should be the same even if not starting with NA. For sure the "Time" column in the result will change if i also start counting at 10 with a value instead of NA. Thanks for pointing to this issue!

Comment: @ all: Thanks for all your answers and comments. After some testing i've decided to use the `rle` approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make my answer complete here a modified version:

```
d <- data.frame( TIME = seq(10, 90, by = 10), Value = c(NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, 30, 68, 0, NA))


aux <- rle(as.numeric((!is.na(d[,2]))))

cbind(TIME = d[cumsum(aux$lengths)[which(aux$values == 1)] - aux$lengths[aux$values == 1] +1, 1],
Result = rle(is.na(d$Value))$lengths[!rle(is.na(d$Value))$values])
     TIME Result
[1,]    2     20
[2,]    3     60
```

Comment: It's likely that `rle` is the answer for their problem, but *this* isn't the answer they are looking for.

Comment: @RStudent +1, Perhaps, you could do `d <- c(NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, 30, 68,0, NA, 2);indx <- which(is.na(d)); d1 <- d[min(indx): max(indx)]; rle(is.na(d1))$lengths[!rle(is.na(d1))$values]`

Comment: @RStudent: I've tested your modified version and it works very well for my need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Apart from `rle`, you can also use a combination of `diff`, `which` and `is.na`:

```
dat <- data.frame(time = seq(10, 90, 10), value = c(NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, 30, 68, 0, NA))
res <- data.frame(result = diff(which(is.na(dat$value))) - 1)
res$time <- dat$time[which(is.na(dat$value)) + 1][1:nrow(res)]
res[res$result != 0, ]
# time result
#   20      2
#   60      3
```

Comment: I've posted a comparison of the results of the different approaches here https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6d76ab08a00e45ac0199. I guess it depends on what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

My ["SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) has [a function called `TrueSeq`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/TrueSeq.R) that is like a group-maker with logical vectors. You can use that function in conjunction with "data.table" to get the result you want, like this:

```
library(SOfun)
library(data.table)
na.omit(data.table(TIME = df$TIME, Val = TrueSeq(
  !is.na(df$value), zero2NA = TRUE)))[, list(TIME = TIME[1], .N), by = Val]
#    Val TIME N
# 1:   1   20 2
# 2:   2   60 3
```

If you have "devtools" installed, you can install "SOfun" with:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")
```

---

For reference, [I've posted this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6d76ab08a00e45ac0199) to be able to compare the results from the different approaches at this answer.

To summarize:

- If the first value in the "values" column is `NA`:

  - All approaches would yield the same answer.
- If the first value in the "values" column is not `NA`:

  - This answer and @RStudent's would be the same, starting with the *first* non-`NA` value (thus, the first row of the input) as the first row of the results.
  - @konvas's answer and @beginneR's would be the same, starting with the *second* non-`NA` value as the first row of the results.

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps not the most straightforward way to do it, but it does produce the desired result and since I wrote it, I thought I might post it, too (using the sample data by @konvas):

```
require(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(m = cumsum(is.na(value))) %>% 
  summarise(n = n() -1, time = first(time[!is.na(value)])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n > 0 & m > 0) %>% 
  select(-m)
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#  n time
#1 2   20
#2 3   60
```

Edit: I made a small correction in response to Ananda's comment, hope it works better now. 
For example, if the data was:

```
dat <- data.frame(time = seq(10, 90, 10), value = c(0, 2, 1, NA, NA, 30, 68, 0, NA))
dat
#  time value
#1   10     0
#2   20     2
#3   30     1
#4   40    NA
#5   50    NA
#6   60    30
#7   70    68
#8   80     0
#9   90    NA
```

The code would result in:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(m = cumsum(is.na(value))) %>% 
  summarise(n = n() -1, time = first(time[!is.na(value)])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n > 0 & m > 0) %>% 
  select(-m)
#Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
#
#  n time
#1 3   60
```

Comment: I was working on a similar solution. But, I could not come up with the `summarise` idea. +1.

Comment: This might need some tweaking if the first value is not `NA`, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you're right. I changed the filter argument and hope it's better now.

Comment: That is a literal "between `NA`s", but I wonder whether the OP wouldn't want the first row in the results to be n = 3 and time = 10. I guess that only the OP knows that :-) +1 for the alternative though.

Comment: @beginneR, for reference, I've posted a comparison of the different approaches here: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6d76ab08a00e45ac0199